# Compare timestamps

Tags: bash, date, timestamps, aws

I am trying to compare timestamp of the latest modified file towards current time and if the diff is more than two hours I am trying to print that out. How can this be done?

The following command shows the timestamp of the file and it has to be compared to the current time.

```
root:/# aws s3 ls --endpoint=https://localhost s3://files/ | tail -n 1 |  awk {'print $1 " "  $2'}
2020-01-22 08:19:00
```

Comment: Doesn't AWS have some sort of `find` command or equivalent tool?

Comment: @Kusalananda not as far as I know.

Comment: Note that you can simplify your awk to `awk '{print $1,$2}'`, it will add a space for you.

Comment: Thanks @terdon. How would you check the diff of the current timestamp and the timestamp I get out of the file? If the timestamp is greater than two hours it should print out something. I believe an `if` should do it?

Comment: You can further simplify your `tail | awk` to `awk 'END {print $1,$2}'`, which will consider only the last line of the input stream.

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: Can you check to see if you have `find` install. If not can you install it. As this will give the simplest answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't specified your OS, but assuming you have GNU `date`, you can convert the date to a timestamp and then perform a simple calculation to determine if it's older than two hours ago:

```
datetime=$(
    aws s3 ls --endpoint=https://localhost s3://files/ |
    awk 'END {print $1, $2}'
)
timestamp=$(date --date "$datetime" +'%s')
timeAgo=$(date --date "2 hours ago" +'%s')

if [[ $timestamp -lt $timeAgo ]]
then
    echo "It's a really old file"
fi
```